# how to pass value from json-rpc and let python read it

Tags: python, json

I added {"value":10} in json-rpc:

```
import requests
import xbmc
import xbmcgui
import xbmcplugin
import xbmcaddon
import json

headers = {
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

data =  '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"Addons.ExecuteAddon","params": 
{"addonid":"script.activatewindowid"},"params":{"value": 10},"id":1}'

response = requests.post('http://192.168.1.200:8080/jsonrpc', 
headers=headers, 
data=data, 
auth=('user', '1234'))
```

And I want the python script can understand the value:10 and use it in his IF function:

```
import json

json_string = what should be here???
parsed_data = json.loads(json_string)
x = parsed_data["value"]


if x == 10:
   xbmc.executebuiltin('ActivateWindow(9000)')
else:
   xbmc.executebuiltin('ActivateWindow(1199)')
```

the json-rpc data reached coerrectly to python script but the python didn't understand how to deal with x value?

Any suggestion to solve this issue please?

Comment: it's `x = parsed_data["params"]["value"]`

Comment: I did 
    [ json_string = get_json_somehow()
     parsed_data = json.loads(json_string)
     x = parsed_data["params"]["value"] ]

but didn't work...!

Comment: It looks like data and parsed_data are not the same data. I'm sorry, it was not obvious to me from your question.

Comment: @VPfB
the data in json-rpc is a method to execute the addon program. Shall I need to add another method to transfer the x value? or like what I did add params value in same method?

Comment: Any Idea from anyone!

Comment: I think the issue now with json_string = get_json_somehow() 
what should be instead of get_json_somehow() ?